# How to retrieve a value from ListView to ASP code at the aspx page

Tags: asp.net, listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="orderID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td>
  <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' Visible="false"  />
</td>
<% 
  Label s = (Label)ListView1.FindControl("statusLabel");
  string status = s.Text;
  if (status == "0") {  //code here }
%>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

How can I get the statusLabel text at front page? not code behind.
Every row of data will be different status, 
so I want to display buttons based on the status.
Any solutions can get this done?

Comment: Why did not you want writing the code in Code behind?

Comment: Is there a set number of buttons? Can you add an example to your question?

Comment: because I want to display different button for every row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need to get the label; you just need to get the value the label is set to, which you can do using the `Eval` function.

If there are a set number of buttons, you can toggle the visibility based on the status:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' Visible="false"  />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test" Visible='<%# Eval("status") == "Open" ? true : false %>' />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Test Again" Visible='<%# Eval("status") == "Closed" ? true : false %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

If the situation is more complex than that, you can use `PlaceHolder` controls to group the buttons by status:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' Visible="false"  />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcOpenStatus" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("status") == "Open" ? true : false %>'>
        <!-- buttons for open status -->
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcClosedStatus" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("status") == "Closed" ? true : false %>'>
        <!-- buttons for closed status -->
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing business logic inline is usually a bad idea. For your case, however, you don't need to access the statusLabel control itself. All you need is to call Eval("status") in your if statement.

So

```
string status = (string) Eval("status");
if (status == "0") { // etc }
```

Comment: Why are you writing the question again in your post? Code mentioned here is exact duplicate of the question.

Comment: @PankajGarg, I suggest you to read more carefully. The author wants to access a control to get its text. It is not necessary because in the same scope he can get the text directly from Eval.

Comment: Please write some code here which is not similar to the code mentioned in question.

Comment: Please compare it urself or download a tool. There are so many free.

Comment: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @AlvisChen, so, are you missing a cast? Hint: string status= (string) Eval("status")

Answer (score 0):

You could attach to the ItemDataBound or ItemCreated events and then execute the code in there.

See this post for an example - http://www.toars.com/2010/11/listview-events-01/